# retrieve signature settings in gmail via api

Tags: php, api, gmail, signature

is it possible to change gmail signature settings using google APIs, I have searched but could not get a clear solution. If it is possible please suggest me how to implement it with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set and retrieve mail signatures for Google Apps domain users with the Email Settings API:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/#manage_signature_settings

Comment: No, the API only supports Google Apps domain users